# how can execute binary file in other system?

Tags: linux, shell, encryption, centos

Basically, i've a shell script configuration for my job. I want give it to my customer. Before it, i want the script is unreadable but executable on another system. So, i've tried to encrypt the script with shc. 
I created a simple script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hallo World"
```

in `tester.sh` on my CentOS7 and encrypted by command `./shc -f tester.sh`. The encrypted file is changed to `tester.sh.x` and renamed to `tester1.sh`. And executed succesfully by command `./tester1.sh`.
Link result on my CentOS7 :
[enter link description here](https://ibb.co/7zHY35g)
Then i tried to copy the file `tester1.sh` to another computer with the same system using SMTP. But on another computer, the file is success unreadable but can't be executed. 
This the result on another CentOS7 
[enter link description here](https://ibb.co/4pty04d)

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Your question is not clear please provide more details on what you have tried and how.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question. Please check..